# как получить SVG картинку с сервера и отобразить в ImageView java android

Tags: java, android, svg

мне приходит ответ в виде ссылки на картинку в SVG формате и я не знаю как ее можно отобразить

пример ссылки "https://s44751.cos.ngenix.net/d0b31aa9-9912-4497-bc13-db50eab90b1f.svg"

помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751595/3212712

Comment: поддерживаю товарища выше. самые простой способ: Glide + AndroidSVG

Comment: Если просто отобразить то можно в WebView